# flutter SUM of fields in a List

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my app I have star rating system implemented. In this case different users give different rating to an item. I later get the sum total of all the ratings and then later get the average, which I display on the UI of the user. When the user clicks on the item, the rating shows in the form of a draggable sheet. Initially, when the button is pressed, it shows the correct average rating as calculated. But then when the button is pressed again the number adds the average to the previous on each click.
That is if (av is actual average) and (n is number of clicks) then the average(A) which is displayed on the UI is A = av*n. This is very disturbing. Is there a better way I can write the code in such a way that no matter how many times I click on the button, the average remains the same?

```
double sum = 0;

Stream<double> getSumRating(String passUID) async* {
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("Collection")
              .doc(docID)
              .collection("Collection")
              .get()
              .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
                    sum += element.get("Stars");
                  }));
          yield sum;
        }

Stream<int> getSumList() async* {
          var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("Collection")
              .doc(docID)
              .collection("Collection")
              .get();
          yield snapshot.docs.length;
        }

ratingBar(
          double rating,
          double size,
          
        ) {
          List<Widget> startList = [];

          int realNum = rating.floor();

          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {}
            if (i < realNum) {
              startList.add(Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: Colors.amber,
                size: size,
              ));
            } else {
              startList.add(Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: Colors.grey,
                size: size,
              ));
            }
          }
          return Row(
            children: startList,
          );
        }

Button(
onPressed:(){
draggrableSheet();
          }
        ),


draggrableSheet() {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            isScrollControlled: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
                initialChildSize: 0.9,
                minChildSize: 0.2,
                maxChildSize: 0.9,
                builder: (context, ScrollController scrollController) {
                  return Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: SizedBox(
                                width: screenWidth * 0.5,
                                child: StreamBuilder(
                                  stream: getSumList(),
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                      return Text(
                                          "Error");
                                    } else {
                                      final sumList = snapshot.data;
                                      final sumOfList = sumList!.toDouble();

                                      return Column(
                                        children: [
                                          StreamBuilder(
                                            stream: getSumRating(passUID),
                                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                              final averageReal =
                                                  sum / sumOfList;
                                              final average = averageReal;

                                              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                                  ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                                              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                                return Text(widget
                                                    .errorLoadingRequestString);
                                              }
                                              if (average.isNaN ||
                                                  average.isInfinite) {
                                                return Column(
                                                  children: [
                                                    ratingBar(0, 20),
                                                    SizedBox(
                                                      height:
                                                          screenHeight * 0.005,
                                                    ),
                                                    
                                                  ],
                                                );
                                              } else {
                                                final averageInt =
                                                    average.floor();
                                                return Column(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Row(
                                                      children: [
                                                        ratingBar(average, 20),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width: screenWidth *
                                                              0.05,
                                                        ),
                                                        Text(
                                                          "$averageInt/5", //this is where the number keeps increasing on every click
                                                          
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    
                                                    
                                                  ],
                                                );
                                              }
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      );
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          );
        }
```

Did I do anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this in your UI builder:

```
return Column(
  children: [
    StreamBuilder(
      stream: getSumRating(passUID),
      ...
```

The `stream` property of a `StreamBuilder` gets reevaluated every time the UI renders, which in your case happens every time you click the button.

---

So your `getSumRating` runs every time you click the button:

```
double sum = 0;

Stream<double> getSumRating(String passUID) async* {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Collection")
      .doc(docID)
      .collection("Collection")
      .get()
      .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
            sum += element.get("Stars");
          }));
  yield sum;
}
```

Since you only set `sum = 0` once, the `sum` increases every time your `getSumRating` is executed, which happens every time the UI render - so every time you click the button.

---

The minimal change to solve the problem is to set `sum` to 0 every time `getSumRating` runs:

```
Stream<double> getSumRating(String passUID) async* {
  sum = 0;
  let value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Collection")
      .doc(docID)
      .collection("Collection")
      .get();
  value.docs.forEach((element) {
    sum += element.get("Stars");
  });
  yield sum;
}
```

While this will work, it still means that you're reloading all documents from the database every time the UI renders and that seems wasteful.

A better approach is to initialize the sum only once and then store it in the state of your widget. So in your [`initState` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) load the data and set it to the state of the widget with something like:

```
int sum = 0;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Collection")
      .doc(docID)
      .collection("Collection")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) {
        setState(() {
          sum = snapshot.docs.fold(0, (prev,doc) => prev + doc.get("Stars") as int);
        })
      ])
}
```

And then render `sum` in your UI, without using a `StreamBuilder` for it.

Comment: `initState()` isn't async. How can you use await in it? The docs for `initState` don't mention being able to do async processing in it. It returns `void`, not `FutureOr<void>`,

Comment: Thanks very much but I'm getting a little bit of error here. When I have (int sum = 0;) the returned => a+b is underlined and says (The return type 'num' isn't a 'int', as required by the closure's context.). When I change it to (double sum = 0;) or (num sum = 0;) only  "b" is underlined in the returned => a+b and says (The argument type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num). 
PS: the field I'm trying to access is save as a number field

Comment: Ah yeah, I oversimplified that last example quite a bit. I updated it now to get the `Stars` value from the document.